# WP7 Listbox Binding: Changing image uri in does not reflect in listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, listbox

I have a view with a list box, bound to am obvervable collection of DisplayItems, which has 'Label', 'DisplayValue' and 'IconUri' properties.
I have a View Model which exposes this observable collection. The List Box is correctly populated first time around.
I then have a button which takes action on the selected item. I need to indicate that action has been taken by changing the image.
I am changing the IconUri of the selected item, and can see the new value present when debugging, but the image doesn't change. I can also change the 'Label' and 'DisplayValue' properties and see the new values correctly there when debugging, but the list doesn't change.
My ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged. My DisplayItem class implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm calling RaisePropertyChanged I'm sure in too many places rather than too few.
None of the changes are ever reflected on screen.

I'm using a DataItemTemplate for the generated rows. If I could access the image of the selected row I could change it manually, but I can't even do that.

Any help greatly appreciated. I could actually do with a example of a list box displaying items from a bound observable collection, where one property of the selected item is changed and that change is reflected in the list box.

Thanks in advance
A

Comment: You may explain what you think your doing but without any code I have no idea. Did you set your views DataContext to the viewmodel? I didn't see that mentioned

Comment: please add you code here, we may help based on that..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly, or you're using it wrong.

Comment: I figure it must be that. Do you have any simple examples of using it?